# how to map single entity with multiple table in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

> I create tour and travel app using xspringboot and Hibernate jpa.in
> that application i have two entity class one is turist and other is
> vechileTtype.I want to map vechiletype entity with turist entity. I
> use xaamp server for my sql database. but when i mapped these two
> entity and run the application i get this type of error

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.main.ToursTravels.model.VechileType column: name (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

> Turist.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;



import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="turist")
@Data
public class Turist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="truist_id")
    private Long truistid;
    @Column(name="turistname")
    private String turistname;
    @Column(name="travel_km")
    private int travelkm;
    @Column(name="travel_date")
    private Date traveldate;
    @Column(name="drivername")
    private String drivername;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="booking_id")
    private VechileType vechiletype;
    @Column(name="vechileno")
    private String vechileno;
    @Column(name="total_amount")
    private BigDecimal totalamount;
    @Column(name="BOOKING_status")
    private boolean bookingstatus;


}
```

> VechileType.java

```
package com.main.ToursTravels.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;



import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="vechiletype")
@Data
public class VechileType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="booking_id")
    private Long  bookingid;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="vechiletype")
    private Turist turist;
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean mini;
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean sedan;
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean suv;
    @Column(name="name_per_km")
    private int rateperkm;
    private BigDecimal minprice;

}
```

> application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/groserystore?useSSL=false & serveTimezone= UTC & useLegacyDateTimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
#use of jpa
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.JPA.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping 3 different properties to the same column `name`:

```
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean mini;
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean sedan;
    @Column(name="name")
    private boolean suv;
```

Use different names instead:

```
    @Column(name="mini")
    private boolean mini;
    @Column(name="sedan")
    private boolean sedan;
    @Column(name="suv")
    private boolean suv;
```

A better, more extensible alternative could be to use an enum:

```
public enum VehicleKind {
   MINI, SEDAN, SUV
}
```

And in `VechileType`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vechiletype")
@Data
public class VechileType {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VehicleKind kind;
```